# How do I reuse the same xml background layout in multiple activities/fragments in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm developing an android app that has the same background image and bottom Navigation bar on almost every activity.

I want to reuse this code instead of writing it out each time:

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image">



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_menu_image"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will be the basic background for all the views; however I'll be placing different layouts over the top of it for each.  Is it possible to use insert and merge tags to start each new activity this way?

Comment: Make a xml of above code and use  

<include
        layout="@layout/your_xml_name"/>

And use this line on every layout of your app's xml

Comment: Will everything I put after that line in the main xml layout be considered inside the LinearLayout in the template xml file?

Comment: @ScottWeller you can put include layout inside any of the parent layout like linear layout,Relative  etc. Yes you can add another layout after <include layout.

Comment: @ScottWeller- Yes. That will be considered inside the your main linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Need xml files call below of it

```
  <include layout="@layout/custom_my_menus" />
```

This is my xml file edit u want like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">


                <!--<ImageView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/img_back"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_header"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Design Collaboration"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="end">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_upload"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/upload_x24"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_collaboration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/lightPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/custom_homeowner_menus" />
    <include layout="@layout/custom_professional_menus" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That part I understand. My question is how do I then include that in a new activity and build on top of it? Will android studio assume whatever code I put after the include statement is inside the linear layout in the xml file?

Comment: @ScottWeller- Adding include means whatever code have you written in 'included layout' will behave like same if you write whole code her, in place of including code.
According to me, you first try and you automatically got to know how it works.